# how to send a push notification from an android app running on a device to another device running the same app?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am new to android and am making a simple app for my college project. The app runs on a simple concept wherein a faculty can know his/her examination duties(which room number is allocated to her for invigilating)and can thus register and login on the app. After logging in, he/she will receive a room number.
He/she can get a list of all other faculties with their respective duties.

Now I want to add another service which will allow a faculty to send a notification to another faculty using the app for swapping room duties.
When sent, another faculty receives a push notification over the net on their app.

I am reading about google gcm but cannot find a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: GCM can use in this case. What is your problem when you said 'I am reading about google gcm but cannot find a solution'?

Comment: I don't know how it is done!

Answer (score 0):

First, you must register your app on GCM, GCM will give you a `regID` with one device. And you must have a server side, the server side stores all regIDs. When you need to push a notification for the other devices, you send a request to your server side, the server side will send a request to GCM with the regIDs (depend on you) then GCM will push notification to all devices. The workflow: 
1. Your phone app will register on GCM, take a regID. Your server side saves this regID.
2. You will send a request to your server side. The server side will use this request to make another request include all or some regIDs, and send this request to GCM.
3. GCM will take regIDs from the request, and push notification to the device which have regID match with one of regID in the request.
For more details, please read this: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm